# Preserve relative references in spreadsheet when using Range.getFormula()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, I'm very new to google script/javascript and I was wondering how to get a formula from one cell and apply it in a second cell. The original formula is referencing a third cell so I'd want the pasted cell to have a new formula where the reference cell is relative to the new positioning. (Just as it would if I used copy & paste on the spreadsheet GUI.)

```js
function myFunction() {
  //Set Spreadsheet "Form Responses 1"
     var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];

  //Set Spreadsheet "Gant"
    var ss3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];

  //Get Last row with value
    var InputRange = ss1.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
    var InputLast = InputRange.filter(String).length;

  //Get Formula which is to be applied to last form entry
    var sourcerange = ss1.getRange(1, 12, 1, 3);
    var sourceformula = sourcerange.getFormula();

    var outputrange = ss1.getRange(1,12,1,3).offset(InputLast - 1, 0);
    outputrange.setFormula(sourceformula);
}
```

So like if the original formula is

```js
 =vlookup(A1, B;C,2,false)
```

the new cell should be something like

```js
 =vlookup(A4, B;C,2,false)
```

Comment: I found out the the code copyto() works for this.

Comment: You should publish your own answer then, so it can help others who may someday have the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that .copyTo() is what solves this problem

Here's the link if anyone's wondering: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range)

Comment: Yup! I found it while looking through the reference site!

Answer (score 0):

`.copyTo()` is fine for the OPs situation. But if you are looping through a range you probably want:

```
var sourceFormulas = sourceRange.getFormulasR1C1();
```

...

```
outputRange.setFormulasR1C1(sourceFormulas);
```

This way you only need to make two API calls; once before the loop and once after. It's **much** faster than calling the API .copyTo() each loop iteration.